# Full width within 980 container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to alter a websites header, footer and its carousel area on the homepage. But because the site was designed to start the 980 container in the header, go throughout the entire site and end in the footer, it therefore constrains all elements throughout the entire site. But I need the header, menu, homepage carousel and footer, to be 100% width.

I know to try break out of the container, but because this site is so large, breaking the container and putting it back in wrapping around just the content on every element (of which are included all over the templates) will take so long because of how many pages the container right now is effecting just isn't great for me right now, is there any other way to do this?

Here's a live preview of the site: http://bit.ly/1kpGc2G

Might not be best practice but just something to get me by for now.

It's opencart encase it helps.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't just start the container after the header divs thus making the header outside the container.

Comment: I don't understand why it should be really bad to edit the width? Parts that fall apart can be fixed. What stops you from editing the width? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for the entire site to fill the screen width?

It seems like you just need to give the 980 container a width of 100%. Then style all the other elements to suit, giving them padding left and right to bring them back into line.

**Edit Example**

You said you didn't mind if it was messy I have this...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Width Test</title>
<style>
    .wrapper {
        width:100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    p {
        color: #ccc;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .header, .article, .footer {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #444;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 600px;
        padding: 0 30%;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .article {
        background-color: #666;
    }
    .footer {
        background-color: #999;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header"><p>Header</p></div>
    <div class="article"><p>Article</p></div>
    <div class="footer"><p>Footer</p></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically I have made this so the padding overflows the wrapper, then used `text-align:center` to centre the content divs. It isn't perfect but I think this achieves what you are asking for.

Comment: But with that, what if padding left and right of 300px is correct for my screen, what about someone elses with a wider screen.

Answer (score 0):

**There are a few issues in your code:**

- There is a text-align:left on the sitewide container
- Most elements have a width:100% directly on the element, meaning they won't be centred. They should have a set width, and max-width:100%;

I.E. I set #category{ width: 1024px; margin: 0 auto;} to get it centered.
Your carousel image does not have a set width, meaning it goes beyond the screen if it is below 1300px. 
**Set img{max-width: 100%;}**.

#footer:
margin: 26px auto; should center it.

I might have forgotten a few things, but this made the site centered for me, including if I zoom in and out, and excludes a potential hoizontal scrollbar.